# Using a handler to send an sms after a period of time?

Tags: java, android, sms, handler

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to send a sms after a period time if a button is not pressed. I'm trying to do this through a handler, but I know that its where I ma trying to state that if the button is not pressed is where my issue lies...

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            if (TakenButton.isActivated() == false) {
                sendSMS(number, "Medication Not Taken");

            }
        }
    }, 20000);
```

The message sends after 20 seconds, but it sends even if the button has been pressed. I'd be very greatful if someone could explain how I can state if the button is not pressed and if im placing it in the correct place?

I now have changed it to this, and I am now getting no message saying medication not taken, however my medication taken is working???

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            sendSMS(number, "Medication Taken");
            isActivated = true;
        }
    });

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {

            if(isActivated = false){
                sendsms();
            }

        }
        private void sendsms() {
            sendSMS(number, "Medication Not Taken");

        }
    }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

THat code can work, with some changes.  Keep the handler variable in a class member (rather than throwing it away) and when the press the button remove any pending messages from the handler.

This will work as long as the phone doesn't go to sleep.  If your timeout is long and the phone may be asleep when it needs to process, you need to set up an alarm.  Handlers like this are good for when you want to delay a few seconds, not a few minutes or longer.